# Optional relationship between two entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have 2 tables:

Site:

```
public class Site
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual PersonDetail Person { get; set; }
}
```

PersonDetail:

```
public class PersonDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Site PbnSite { get; set; }
}
```

A site doesn't necessarily have a person, nor does a person necessarily have a site. The relationship is thus optional on both ends.
I get the error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'Site' and 'PersonDetail'. The principal end of this association
>   must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API
>   or data annotations.

When trying to update my database using this schema.
I know a solution would be to set one of them as required but seeing as none of them really are required I'd naturally assume that there would be a way to create an optional relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **one-to-one** relation one end must be **principal** and second end must be **dependent**. Override the `OnModelCreating` method in your Context class and try this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<PersonDetail>()
    .HasOptional(p => p.PbnSite)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal(s => s.Person);
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken this could have been done in either direction and only done once (not defining in both directions)?

Comment: you welcome. As @ErikPhilips said, It may have been defined in any of the two directions, it depends of your logic to decide who is the principal